# Expensive tires or cheap tires to trade in

Tags: united-states, car

I am planning on buying a new car by the end of next summer (it is February now) but the tread on my current tires is shot and we get a lot of snow where I live. So for safety reasons, I definitely need to get new tires but my question is: Do I buy the expensive tires now since I am planning on keeping it for at least 1 more year or do I go cheap since I'm planning on trading in most likely before it comes time to replace the tires again (the difference in price for this car is approx $300? Will good tires affect the trade-in/sale value of the car?

Comment: tires do not alter trade in value.

Answer (score 8):

Tire manufacturers suggest that tires should last 60,000 miles.  New tire warranties tend to be for 60 to 80 thousand miles.

Apart from mileage driven, a number of factors affect this life expectancy of tires.  Some of them are sun exposure, the amount of temperature change, proper inflation, the composition of the roads that you drive on and how you drive (normal versus 'peeling out').

IMO, if you're going to buy a new car by next summer, buy the less expensive  tires.  More expensive tires will not affect the trade in value.  Only the quality of the remaining tread will, if the tires are bald.

Answer (score -1):

Will it be best to sell it with good tires on it? The price of it as what was mentioned above will depend on its quality as well. Both the dealer and prospective buyers will check the car before determining the price. It doesn't have to be the most expensive tire model.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Unless you have some sort of high-performance car, most potential buyers won't know the difference between "good" tires and ordinary tires - if indeed there actually IS a real difference.